# tracking memory usage and garbage collection in R

Tags: r, memory, garbage-collection

I am running functions which are deeply nested and consume quite a bit of memory as reported by the Windows task manager. The output variables are relatively small (1-2 orders of magnitude smaller than the amount of memory consumed), so I am assuming that the difference can be attributed to intermediate variables assigned somewhere in the function (or within sub-functions being called) and a delay in garbage collection. So, my questions are:

1) Is my assumption correct? Why or why not?

2) Is there any sense in simply nesting calls to functions more deeply rather than assigning intermediate variables? Will this reduce memory usage?

3) Suppose a scenario in which R is using 3GB of memory on a system with 4GB of RAM. After running gc(), it's now using only 2GB. In such a situation, is R smart enough to run garbage collection on its own if I had, say, called another function which used up 1.5GB of memory?

There are certain datasets I am working with which are able to crash the system as it runs out of memory when they are processed, and I'm trying to alleviate this. Thanks in advance for any answers!

Josh

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) Memory used to represent objects in R and memory marked by the OS as in-use are separated by several layers (R's own memory handling, when and how the OS reclaims memory from applications, etc.). I'd say (a) I don't know for sure but (b) at times the task manager's notion of memory use might not accurately reflect the memory actually in use by R, but that (c) yes, probably the discrepancy you describe reflects memory allocated by R to objects in your current session.

2) In a function like

```
f = function() { a = 1; g=function() a; g() }
```

invoking `f()` prints `1`, implying that memory used by `a` is still being marked as in use when `g` is invoked. So nesting functions doesn't help with memory management, probably the reverse.

Your best bet is to clean-up or re-use variables representing large allocations before making more large allocations. Appropriately designed functions can help with this, e.g.,

```
f = function() { m = matrix(0, 10000, 10000); 1 }
g = function() { m = matrix(0, 10000, 10000); 1 }
h = function() { f(); g() }
```

The large memory of `f` is no longer needed by the time `f` returns, and so is available for garbage collection if the large memory required for `g` necessitates this.

3) If R tries to allocate memory for a variable and can't, it'll run its garbage collector a and try again. So you don't gain anything by running `gc()` yourself.

I'd make sure that you've written memory efficient code, and if there are still issues I'd move to a 64bit platform where memory is less of an issue.

Answer (score 5):

R has facilities for memory profiling, but it needs to be built that. While we enable that for Debian / Ubuntu, I do not know what the default for Windows is.

Usage of memory profiling is discussed (briefly) in the 'Writing R Extensions' manual.

Coping with (limited) memory on a 32-bit system (and particularly Windows) has its challenges.  Most people will recommend that you switch to a system with as much RAM as possible running a 64-bit OS.